# when and why should I override logical id in CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

When the logical id of a resource changes, CDK would delete the old resource with the old logical id, and create a new resource with the new logical id. There are concerns that critical resources may change unexpectedly causing disruptions.

CDK provides a [method on CfnResource to override logical id](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.CfnResource.html#overridewbrlogicalwbridnewlogicalid)

when and why do I need manage the logical id myself?

Comment: There isn't a list of use-cases for this, the functionality is there for when you know you need it. For example, if you change the ID of a parent Construct but don't want its child resources to be recreated. If you don't know for sure that you need to do it, then you probably don't.